# Chrome keeps redirecting me to https

Tags: google-chrome, web

I made a web page, its hosted on a server with no ssl support (nor does it need any). Anyways, all was well when I handed it over couple weeks ago but since yesterday something weird started happening.

On some computers (like half that I've tried), chrome automatically redirects the website to https which doesn't work so you get the warning page. I tried emptying the browser cache, restarting the browser, reinstalling the browser but it still happens, when i do a clean install and type in http://mysitename.com it still goes to https://mysitename.com, and only on those computers, I just don't get it.

On the flipside, on the computers where the page works fine, when I type in the https url into chrome, it goes to the http page, as it should.

What could be going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome added a "HTTPS: 1" header by default in its last version.
As a result, Chrome asks your server to respond with the HTTPS version if available.

=> You have either to disable the SSL mod on your server, or to deploy a valid certificate on it.

Comment: Its a virtual apache server, .htaccess is as close as I can get to configuring it. I tried fiddling with that but cant seem to disable https. Either way thats ridiculous, why is google forcing people to buy ssl certs on purely informational sites that have no user input?

Comment: I think it was just an experiment that turned out really bad :). They plan to force people using SSL, but the Internet is not ready yet.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, would have been nice to hear about this. I had the site working fine on Thursday night (no SSL installed) and by Friday, Chrome (and only Chrome) is showing it as a security risk (on antivirus) because it's redirecting to wrong domain.

I've tried all the fixes. Now I guess it's SSL or nothing?